# Tagging certain views to behave alike

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, android-view

**Scenario**
I am integrating in-app payments in my Android app for some of the features that will be unlocked once a user pays and becomes a Pro user. The idea is to show the views leading to Pro functionality throughout the app to both free and paid users. But,

- for free users, the app shows a Pro badge with these views. Whenever a free user clicks a Pro view or control, the available payment plans are shown along with the UI to become a Pro user.
- for Pro users, clicking a Pro view leads them to the UI to use these features.

**Problem**
The goto approach of doing this is adding `if/else` in `onClickListener` of all of these views to lead user to different parts of the app based on whether they are Pro or not. But since there are many Pro features, adding repeated `if/else` statements to each of their `onClickListener` will make the code look ugly.

**Required Solution**
I want to have a way to tag all the Pro views in such a way that can let the code know that for a free user, clicking these views will open the UI to become a Pro user, and once a user has become a Pro user, clicking these views will lead them to the relevant feature screens. Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to stick with the standard approach as I said above?

Comment: No, these views are present throughout the app in multiple activities/fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use data binding for visibility of views

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="isPro"
        type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout android:visibility="@{isPro? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>
```

Comment: Actually, I thought about it, but there is a problem with this approach. I don't want to hide the views that trigger the Pro features. I want to show these views, but perform different click actions on them for users based on their Free/Pro status.